# Scanner for OWASP top 10 verbose report

Tags: security, owasp

I'm looking for a OWASP top 10 scanner which is able to produce a report with all tests in it.
Not only the hits, everything.
Every scanner I have tested only shows positives.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Zaproxy](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy) for that - see this [page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAPpingTheTop10) for more details about using it to scan for OWASP top 10.

Any scanner you will use will have false positives, you can use a tool like [Glue](https://github.com/OWASP/glue) to filter false positives.

Comment: Yes, I know Zaproxy. But it only shows the positives (and false positives) but not all tests which has been made in it's reports.

Comment: why do you need all the tests? also might worth to mention that in the question (e.g. tools that you already tried and why you didn't like them)

Comment: It has been requested by a client. I testet OWASP ZAP, Nessus (does not scan OWASP top 10), OpenVAS, tenable.io Web Application, Netsparker Web Scanner

Comment: Well, you can use Zap API to get all the rules, and the document above to get the mapping between the rule to top 10. You should also see the rule id in the HTML result so you can link rule to result...